# Mocha watch doesnt trigger on new files

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

When i run mocha on watch

```
mocha --watch app/**/*.spec.js
```

Everything is working fine. Unless when I create new spec file mocha doesnt detect that.

Is there ani fix for it?

Comment: Any update on this?  I've got the same issue.

Comment: @ironchamber I just get used to rerun command on new file create. Not big deal

Comment: Fair enough, I'm doing much the same over here.  I just put more tests in a single file than I did before.

Answer (score 3):

This seems likely to be a bug or an unimplemented feature. There is an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2176) filed on the Mocha repo.